# MS Access, new record sometimes creates two records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have query results in a subform which is manipulated via buttons outside of the subform.

Image of the form:

[image: Image of the form]

Pretty much all the 'Add Record' button does is run an INSERT statement and refreshes the form/query. The INSERT statement contains mostly the same information as whats in the previous rows; information that won't change such as DLA_HOLDER_ID, DLA_TYPE_ID, etc. It leaves most other fields blank for entry and uses `Date()` and `Time()` for `DLA_CREATION_DATE` and `RECORD_DATE` respectively.

When a row is added, the TEMP_STATUS is `'N'`, once saved it becomes `'S'` and if canceled an UPDATE statement is ran deleting rows that satisfy the query results with `TEMP_STATUS` `'N'`. This all works perfectly.

My issue is, *sometimes* when pressing 'Add Record', two rows are inserted. It might only happen say 5%-10% of the time and occurs at random. When the two rows are added, they are the exact same except for the `RECORD_TIME` being one second apart. I.e row1 = 2:06:24 PM, row2 = 2:06:25 PM.

Is there a way to fix this? The only way I can think of this happening is by chance the time taken to process the INSERT query, the `Time()` value could change from say 2:06:24 to 2:06:25 and instead of picking one it inserts both. (Yes I understand it *shouldn't* work that way, but it's all I can think of.)

**EDIT**
Here is the code for the 'Add Record' button. The button simply cannot be pressed twice as it requires either the 'Save Record' or 'Cancel' buttons to be pressed to re-enable the 'Add Record' button.

```
Private Sub cmdNewRec_Click()

insert_query = "INSERT INTO DLA_RELATIONSHIP (DLA_HOLDER_ID, DLA_TYPE_ID, DLA_LOCATION_ID, DLA_PARAMETER_ID, DLA_TITLE, DLA_CREATION_DATE, TEMP_STATUS) SELECT DLA_HOLDER_ID, DLA_TYPE_ID, DLA_LOCATION_ID, DLA_PARAMETER_ID, DLA_TITLE, DLA_CREATION_DATE, ('N') AS TEMP_STATUS FROM DLA_RELATIONSHIP WHERE (((DLA_HOLDER_ID)= txt1) And ((DLA_TYPE_ID)= txt2) And ((DLA_LOCATION_ID)=txt6) and ((DLA_PARAMETER_ID)= txt3) And ((DLA_TITLE)=txt4) And ((DLA_CREATION_DATE)=txt5))"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL insert_query
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Form.refresh

lblNotice1.Caption = "New record present with unsaved changes"

cmdNewRec.Enabled = False
cmdSave.Enabled = True
cmdCancel.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Again, keep in mind it occurs at complete random (again leading me to thinking it is the Time() function  somehow playing in to this).

Comment: a person can also has a wobbly mouse button and clicks twice

Comment: ...yes, not in this case.

Comment: To find the cause, you need to edit your post and add your "Add record" code to it. But you could simply check at the beginning of that procedure, if a "N" record exists already.

Comment: Would it be possible to disable the button until the insert is finished to test if this remedies the problem?

Comment: @Andre I have added the code.

Comment: @Serv This essentially already happens as it requires either the 'Save Record' or 'Cancel' buttons to be pressed to re-enable the 'Add Record' button.

Comment: Your WHERE clause should **only** have (and need) the column(s) of the Primary key of `DLA_RELATIONSHIP`. If it hasn't a PK, create one. That would be cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding `TOP 1` to the select on your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO DLA_RELATIONSHIP (DLA_HOLDER_ID, DLA_TYPE_ID, DLA_LOCATION_ID, DLA_PARAMETER_ID, DLA_TITLE, DLA_CREATION_DATE, TEMP_STATUS) 
SELECT TOP 1 DLA_HOLDER_ID, DLA_TYPE_ID, DLA_LOCATION_ID, DLA_PARAMETER_ID, DLA_TITLE, DLA_CREATION_DATE, ('N') AS TEMP_STATUS 
FROM DLA_RELATIONSHIP 
WHERE (((DLA_HOLDER_ID)= txt1) And ((DLA_TYPE_ID)= txt2) And ((DLA_LOCATION_ID)=txt6) and ((DLA_PARAMETER_ID)= txt3) And ((DLA_TITLE)=txt4) And ((DLA_CREATION_DATE)=txt5))
```

If this fixes your issue, then the where condition is returning more than one record for the select, which would get two rows inserted.

However, you probably should be inserting the record directly from the values in your text boxes as opposed to selecting them from the table; that would make the select unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Kateract, so simple! 

I appreciate the help.